# How to configure load balancer Nginx between client-server witch based on socket?

Tags: spring-boot, sockets, nginx, load-balancing

I implemented two client and server applications that communicate using socket (rosocket). Now I want to launch many of server and setup Nginx as load balancer. I have problem with second part

Server was implemented base on Spring Boot **127.0.0.1:7002**:

```
@ConnectMapping(Credential.CLIENT_LOGIN_TO_MANAGER)
public void connectClient(RSocketRequester requester ) {
     log.info("New client");
}
```

Client **ip/port 127.0.0.1:8020**:

```
RSocketRequester.Builder rBuilder;
...
rBuilder.setupRoute(Credential.CLIENT_LOGIN_TO_MANAGER)
        .rsocketFactory(config)
        .connectTcp(ip, port)
        .block();
```

Nginx 1.18 file: sites-enabled/default:

```
upstream task-api {
    server 127.0.0.1:7002;
}
 
server {
    listen 8020;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://task-api;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
}
```

Direct client and server connection is working correctly. I have no idea how to jump the problem.

Nginx log:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Jul/2020:17:36:28 +0200] "\x00\x00h\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00N \x00\x01_\x90'message/x.rsocket.composite-metadata.v0\x10application/cbor\x00\x00\x1A\xFE\x00\x00\x16\x15login-client-endpoint" 400 166 "-" "-"
```

Client log:

```
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
2020-07-12 17:36:29.815  INFO 82370 --- [           main] pl.lasota.crm.plugins.ccc.TaskClientApi  : Started TaskClientApi in 1.984 seconds (JVM running for 2.621)
```

Server log:

```
2020-07-12 17:36:06.728  INFO 82210 --- [           main] o.s.b.rsocket.netty.NettyRSocketServer   : Netty RSocket started on port(s): 7002
2020-07-12 17:36:06.744  WARN 82210 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2020-07-12 17:36:06.779  INFO 82210 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8081 (http) with context path ''
2020-07-12 17:36:06.782  INFO 82210 --- [           main] pl.lasota.crm.cfa.server.TaskServerApi   : Started TaskServerApi in 2.576 seconds (JVM running for 3.261)
```

Answer (score 0):

I  found solution. Only need to change transport type from TCP to Websocket. For Spring Boot server:

```
spring.rsocket.server.port=7002
spring.rsocket.server.transport=websocket
```

and for client:

```
rBuilder.setupRoute(Credential.CLIENT_LOGIN_TO_MANAGER)
        .rsocketFactory(config)
        .connectWebSocket(URI.create("http://127.0.0.1:8020"))
        .block();
```

I am not convinced that it is possible to configure nginx to solve with TCP. Maybe someone else find.